Extending Diffeomorphisms of Lie Manifolds
Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold that is diffeomorphic to a Lie group $G$ and $N$ be a connected smooth submanifold of $M$ that is diffeomorphic to a Lie group $H$. Can every diffeomorphism of $N$ be extended to a diffeomorphism of $M$?
It does not have to be unique, I am just interested in whether there exists a diffeomorphism of $M$ that matches any diffeomorphism of $N$ when restricted to $N$.
Note that $H$ is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$, consider for example a circle embedded in two-dimensional Euclidean space.

Not assuming $N$ is connected:
Let $H \cong S^1 \times \mathbb Z_3$ which topologically is the disjoint union of $3$ circles embedded as $H$ concentrically into $M = G = \mathbb R^2$ in such a way that $S^2 \times \{0\}$ is the smallest circle, while $S^1 \times \{2\}$ is the largest circle. Let $f$ be the diffeomorphism of $N$ which interchanges the circles $S^1 \times \{0\}$ and $S^1 \times \{1\}$. This cannot extend to a diffeomorphism $M \to M$, by the following argument: Let $\gamma$ be an path which connects $S^1 \times \{2\}$ and $S^1 \times \{1\}$ radially. If $f$ even had a continuous extension, this extension would map $\gamma$ onto an arc that connects $S^1 \times \{0\}$ and $S^1 \times \{2\}$ but does not cross $S^1 \times \{1\}$, which is impossible.

Assuming $N$ is connected
Let $\mathbb T = S^1 \times S^1 = H$ be embedded into $M = G=\mathbb R^3$ in the usual way. Let $f$ be the diffeomorphism of $\mathbb T$ that swaps meridian and longitude of the Torus as suggested by @Moishe Kohan in the comments. If $f$ had an extension to $\mathbb R^3$, then consider the disk bounded by some longitude of $\mathbb T$. This is fully inside the torus. Under $f$ the longitude gets mapped to the meridian, so in particular the image of this disc is now bounded by the meridian and does not intersect the torus in any other place. Hence it gets mapped to the outside of the torus.
We can deduce that the extension of $f$ swaps the inner and outer connected components of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \mathbb T^2,$ but this is impossible, as the inner one is homotopic to $S^1\times (\mathbb D^2)^o$ while the outer one is diffeomorphic $S^1\times (\mathbb D^2)^o \setminus \{*\}$

Thank you for sharing this! But yeah I am actually more interested in the connected case. I will edit the question

I think there might be a way to embed a $2$-Torus $\mathbb T = S^1 \times S^1$ into $\mathbb R^3$ and construct $f$ in such a way that any extension of $f$ would have to flip the inner and outer connected components of $\mathbb R^3 \setminus \mathbb T$, but they are topologically distinct, so we would again reach a contradiction, but I can't figure out the exact argument right now.

Unfortunately there's no way to embed $\mathbb T$ as a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb R^3$, because $\mathbb R^3$ with its usual additive Lie group structure has no nontrivial compact subgroups. One might have better luck embedding $\mathbb T$ into a higher dimensional Lie group such as $SO(4)$...

But Jannis does not require H to be embedded as a subgroup of G. @Lee Mosher

Ah, good point, I did not read the post carefully enough. Then your comment example works just fine.

The 2-Torus idea is interesting but I can't see why it would ever be necessary to flip the inner and outer connected components when creating an extension.

Just swap the meridian and longitude of the torus.

This is certainly the easiest way to do it. I've added a construction to my answer.
